# How to create short words stored in database that represents longs text when typed in textbox c#

Tags: c#, database, c#-3.0

How do I make an c# application with a database where I store values in database, eg let's say in `column(CName)"xr"` = `column(Description) "Go to sleep"` and  `column(CName) "vs"` = `column(Description) "at 10 pm"` and these values will be stored in database and when I type "xr vs" in a textbox the string "Go to sleep at 10 pm" will be displayed on another textbox in a form.

Now when i write any text in the `bunifuTextBox2` all values in the Description column are showing in the other textbox called `TAbunifuTextBox10`, how do I call specific values using method below?

Database table
{**CName**  , xr , vs}
{**Description**  , Go to sleep , at 10 pm}

```
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-EU4PTNQ;Initial Catalog=Medrive;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"))
            {
                con.Open();
              
                if (bunifuTextBox2.Text != "")
                {
                    string DescriptionQueryStr = "Select CName from Ciphers";
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(DescriptionQueryStr, con))
                    {
                        
                        string[] tbVals = bunifuTextBox2.Text.Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                        for (int i = 0; i < tbVals.Length; i++)
                        {
                           DescriptionQueryStr = "where Description=@Description" + i.ToString() + "OR";
                           cmd.Parameters.Add("@Description" + i.ToString(), SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = tbVals[i];
                        }
                        //Strip off the last OR
                        DescriptionQueryStr = DescriptionQueryStr.Substring(0, DescriptionQueryStr.Length - 2);
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                        using (SqlDataReader da = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            if (da.Read())
                            {
                                var hasAnotherRecord = true;
                                while (hasAnotherRecord)
                                {
                                    sb.AppendLine(da.GetValue(0).ToString());
                                    hasAnotherRecord = da.Read();
                                    if (hasAnotherRecord )
                                        sb.Append('-');
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        TAbunifuTextBox10.Text = sb.ToString();
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: im new guys i need your help

Comment: You can call the query on textbox textchanged method

Comment: @viveknuna the code is under textchanged event but it is not working properly

Comment: Output the generated query and check what it looks like. There are wrong things there

Comment: @Cid how do i do that?? i was using visual studio

Comment: [`Debug.WriteLine();`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debug.writeline?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: @Cid nothing is happening

Comment: i need help on the query